# UserNotAuthenticated Exception during initSign on Android

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-biometric-prompt

I'm seeing app crashes in production on Android 12 and 13 (so far) as follows when calling `Signature.initSign`:

```
android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException: User not authenticated
    at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:128)
    at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:217)
    at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineInitSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:123)
    at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineInitSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:101)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1357)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1310)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1385)
    at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:679)
```

The flow I'm following is:

1. generate a key pair in the android keystore with a sole purpose of
   `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN`. The code is similar to the `KeyPairGenerator` sample here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UsingAndroidKeyStore (In my case `UserAuthenticationRequired` is
   true, `invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment` is false)
2. later, when signing is required, retrieve the private key from the keystore and call initSign(`privateKey`)
3. Now launch the BiometricPrompt (passing in the initialised Signature as part of the Cipher object)
4. Once the user has successfully authenticated, then call `Signature.update` and `Signature.sign` on the returned Signature.

I might expect the crash at step 4 if the user had failed to authenticate, or if a weak authenticator was used, but this crash is happening at step 2 when calling `initSign`. The user can't have authenticated here, as initSign must be called on the signature before passing it to the biometric prompt.

What could cause this? The crashes occur across multiple devices and once users experience this it repeats consistently, so doesn't seem to be a rare edge case. I cannot replicate this locally on a variety of devices on Android 12 and 13 so in theory the flow works.